# Deleting and making files with os isn't working

Tags: python, operating-system

For some reason whenever I use os.rmdir or os.removedirs and os.makedirs or os.mkdir
it doesn't work. My code is

```
import os

path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\New Text Document.txt"

os.rmdir(path)
```

and the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\projects\projects in python files\security\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.rmdir(path)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test\\New Text Document.txt'
```

My computer has only one \

Comment: That looks like a text file not a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os
path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\New Text Document.txt"
os.remove(path)
```

Use **os.remove(path)**

**os.rmdir(path)** is used to delete an empty directory not a file

Comment: Thanks so musch!! I didn't know that